# JSON Schema - array with multiple different object types

Tags: yaml, jsonschema

I'm writing a schema using `draft/2020-12` to validate an array of multiple objects. I will be using YAML for the examples for readability (and it's YAML documents that are going to be validated).

I've seen many different approaches but none seem to do a very good job for some reason.

### The data to validate

```yaml
pipeline:
  - foo: abc
    someOption: 123
  - baz: def
    anotherOption: 223
  - foo: ghi
```

As you can see, the `pipeline` array contains objects that has completely different properties. The same object types can appear multiple times (there's 2 instances of an object containing `foo`, they are to be seen as the same object type).

### Schema

```yaml
$id: 'https://example.com/schema'
$schema: 'https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema'
type: object
properties: 
  pipeline:
    type: array
    additionalItems: false
    anyOf:
      - items:
          type: object
          additionalProperties: false
          properties:
            foo:
              type: string
            someOption: 
              type: integer
          required: [foo]
      - items:
          type: object
          additionalProperties: false
          properties:
            baz: 
              type: string
            anotherOption:
              type: integer
          required: [baz]
```

To me, this looks correct, although it [fails validation](https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/s/Q8aR7s0R) and I can't quite see why...

Even if it *had* worked, I'm not sure if I'm supposed to use `anyOf` or `oneOf` in this case. Is it matching across all array items or per individual array item?

Comment: `additionalItems` was removed from the `2020-12` spec. jsonschemavalidator.net does not handle 2020-12 yet. json-schema.hyperjump.io does handle 2020-12. Besides, I think you can remove your use of it, as it would cause validation to fail. It is being ignored right now though, regardless.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have it slightly wrong. Currently your schema says... for the pipeline array, either, all of the items must be `foo` or all of the items must be `baz`.

You need to change your location of `anyOf` and `items`...

`items` applies to every item in the array.
`anyOf` checks that any of the subschema values are valid against the instance location (in this case, each item in the array).

```
{
  "$id": "https://example.com/schema",
  "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "pipeline": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "anyOf": [
          {
            "type": "object",
            "additionalProperties": false,
            "properties": {
              "foo": {
                "type": "string"
              },
              "someOption": {
                "type": "integer"
              }
            },
            "required": [
              "foo"
            ]
          }, {
            "type": "object",
            "additionalProperties": false,
            "properties": {
              "baz": {
                "type": "string"
              },
              "anotherOption": {
                "type": "integer"
              }
            },
            "required": [
              "baz"
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I was sure this was one of the variations I had already tested, but now when I tried it again it seems to work.

Comment: `additionalItems` should still be removed from the schema, as it does nothing in draft2020-12.

Comment: Thanks @Ether, I'll update to reflect.